# Alternative to using span?

Tags: html, css

Here is an example.

```
<span id="s1">Hello</span>
<span id="s2">world</span>
<span id="s3">this</span>
<span id="s4">is</span>
<span id="s5">a</span>
<span id="s6">sentence.</span>
```

Basically, I have a script that separates words of a sentence into a `span`. Is there a better approach of doing this? Perhaps an alternative to `span` that I don't know about? I thought of using something like `<u>` because it is short, then removing default underlining. Also `<p>` wont work because it is a block element.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't think of anything. Out of curiosity, what issue do you have with `span`?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use `<span>`? It doesn't seem like there's any semantics behind what you're doing that maps to HTML concepts so `<span>` seems appropriate. (Where HTML mostly concerns itself with a logical document outline.)

Comment: I'm not advising this, but just to let you know, you can make a `<p>` behave like a `<span>` by using `p { display: inline }`

Comment: what you are trying to achieve? you can use p,a,div,span,u etc etc, then use css. tags have a default use, but css can change it so different tags act the same.

Comment: If you can imagine, I am generating thousands of words, and I need to be able to style/select each idividual element differently (not going to get into that) I am not happy with span because it renders too much unnessesary html. I thought there might be a psuedo selector or something i could use?

Comment: If your disposition to the `<span>` tag is bandwidth I'd suggest using javascript to convert the sentences into word elements. As far as I know there is no other way to select/target specific words using CSS or anything avoiding additional mark up.

Comment: We have here a dupe ping-pong (orig is closed as the dupe of this), I suggest a reopen. ([List of all such questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1092910/question-pairs-closed-as-the-dupe-of-each-other))

Answer (score 6):

For semantics reasons, I'd advise against using other elements, unless there's some real need for you  to have shorter element names. `<span>`s are semantically neutral elements, so they'd be ideal for this situation.

Comment: If you can imagine, I am generating thousands of words, and I need to be able to style/select each idividual element differently (not going to get into that) I am not happy with span because it renders too much unnessesary html. I thought there might be a psuedo selector or something i could use?

Comment: Currently, there aren't any word-based pseudo selectors, so you're out of luck in that area... As far as page size is concerned, I wouldn't be too worried about it unless bandwidth is a huge concern. (also, [the standard is to use `<span>`s for word/token-based highlighting](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/jquery.js), despite the size)

Comment: Semantics aside (which I'd recommend following anyway), you could just use another tag and restyle it such that it has no visual impact on the page. (available one-letter tags would be `<a>`, `<b>`, `<i>`, `<p>`, `<q>`, and `<u>`)

Comment: @TrevorMartin: The size is probably of very little consequence. Are you using compression?

Comment: @minitech What do you mean by compression? Just removing the whitespace in the HTML?

Comment: @TrevorMartin: That and Gzip, e.g..

Answer (score 3):

This is probably exactly what you should be doing if you really need to style each word differently. It's a meaningless tag used to group inline elements (in this case, words).

[The span element .. doesn't mean anything on its own ..](http://developers.whatwg.org/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element)

Answer (score 1):

The `span` element is the only element in HTML that has been defined as not meaning anything as such, so it is the element to be used when you wish to make e.g. a word an element in order to manipulate it, without assigning any meaning to it.

However, an `a` element without an `href` attribute is also “semantically” empty and with no default rendering rules. Some people have used `<a id=foo>...</a>` instead `<span id=foo>...</span>`. However, some programs may process such an `a` element in some special way (as if it were link-like anyway), and people may write style sheets in a manner that expects all `a` elements to be links. So such use of `a` is risky with no benefit beyond shortness. It also makes the source code less legible, since such use is not common.

In practice, you could, up to a point, use a custom tag, like `z` (with `document.createElement('z')` in JavaScript to make old versions of IE treat it as styleable). Browsers would treat it as unknown element, letting you handle it in scripting and (with the caveat) in CSS. But imagine what happens if some future version of HTML, or HTML as recognized by some browser, contains an element with the name you selected, with some fancy meaning and effect (like “don’t display this element” or “blink this text”).

Comment: Modern browsers handle undefined tags as creating elements with no specific meaning (formally, as corresponding to HTMLUnknownElement objects). The `document.createElement('z')` is just a trick to make old versions of IE behave the same way.

Comment: `a` without `href` is a placeholder for a link, not a semantically empty tag. See the spec: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: @imjared, “the element represents a placeholder for where a link might otherwise have been placed, if it had been relevant, consisting of just the element's contents” is just a somewhat obscure way of saying “no meaning”.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with the answers [Nightfirecat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19085087/1091386) and [imjared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19085091/1091386) posted. `<span>` is probably the best element to use in this case as it denotes a neutral inline element.

However, if you really had to stretch a hack, you could try `<em>` since you are emphasising each word in its own way.

Comment: *I'm not sure I'd agree with this, since you'd essentially be emphasizing the whole sentence, which isn't the intent.*